# Extracting Freeform Shapes from PPTX and Plotting with Python

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I am working on a project where I need to extract freeform shapes from a PowerPoint (PPTX) file and then plot them using Python. I have already explored various libraries, such as python-pptx for reading PPTX files, but I'm struggling to extract freeform shapes specifically.

I done me search and found this: [How to extract FREEFORM shapes from ppt and save it in png file using pptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72214385/how-to-extract-freeform-shapes-from-ppt-and-save-it-in-png-file-using-pptx) but that isn't enough.

I managed to solve it by converting to html using aspose but I don't want to use online services.

I am searching for services-free solution. I'm willing to switch / add another programming language

Comment: The referenced item goes the XML route - which I'd consider difficult at best. When you get hold of the free form shape object can you read the various parts of it? (I have no experience of reading one but I know from doing it the API lets you create a free form shape; My hope is the API has "getter" methods as well as "setter".) The next issue will be parsing what you get back and converting it to whatever output API you're using.